# Cannot subscript a value of type '[HTTPCookiePropertyKey : Any]' with an index of type 'String'

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift4

> Error: Cannot subscript a value of type `[HTTPCookiePropertyKey : Any]` with an index of type String

Code:

```
func copyCookiesForEx() {
    if let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies(for: NSURL(string: kEHentaiURL)! as URL) {
        print(cookies)
        for c in cookies {
            if var properties = c.properties {
                properties["Domain"] = ".exhentai.org" -< error is here
                if let newCookie = HTTPCookie(properties: properties) {
                    HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie(newCookie)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message states clearly what the issue is. `properties` is of type `Dictionary<HTTPCookiePropertyKey,Any>`, so you can't use a `String` as a key for subscripting.

You have to use `HTTPCookiePropertyKey.domain` instead of `"domain"`.

You also shouldn't use `NSURL(string:)` and then cast it to `URL` when you can simply use the same init method of `URL` directly.

```
func copyCookiesForEx() {
    if let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies(for: URL(string: kEHentaiURL)!) {
        if var properties = c.properties {
            properties[.domain] = ".extentai.org" // HTTPCookiePropertyKey.domain
            if let newCookie = HTTPCookie(properties: properties) {
                HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie(newCookie)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4 introduces a lot of new key structs for reliability and robustness.

It's simply

```
properties[.domain] = ".exhentai.org"
```

Please read the documentation of [HTTPCookiePropertyKey](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/httpcookiepropertykey)

---

And don't use `NSURL` with ugly cast to `URL` in Swift 3+, use always native struct `URL`

```
... cookies(for:URL(string: kEHentaiURL)!) { ...
```